# How to compute $\mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(pX-qY)] $ and $\mathbb{E}[pX\mathbb{1}(pX-qY>0)]$ where $X\sim B(K, q), Y\sim B(K, p)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ are two independent binomial random variables where $X\sim B(K, q), Y\sim B(K, p)$. I am wondering how to compute or estimate the following expectations:
$$ \ \mathbb{E}[|pX-qY|]\ \  \text{and}\ \ \mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(pX-qY)].$$

where ReLU($x$) = max($x, 0$) Furthermore, what does the distribution of $pX-qY$ look like?

Update: Actually I'm more interested in $\mathbb{E}[pX\mathbb{1}(pX-qY>0)]\  \text{and}\  \mathbb{E}[qY\mathbb{1}(pX-qY>0)]$, where $\mathbb{1}$ is the indicator function. We know that $\mathbb{E}[pX\mathbb{1}(pX-qY>0)]-\mathbb{E}[qY\mathbb{1}(pX-qY>0)]=\mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(pX-qY)]$.

Comment: The title doesn't reflect the question. The question in the title is trivial due to the linearity of expectation, whereas the question in the body of the text leads to a double sum for which I don't think there's a closed form.

Comment: It does not look pretty to me, though I think you can say $\mathbb{E}[|pX-qY|] = \mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(pX-qY)] +  \mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(qY-pX)] =2 \mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(pX-qY)]$.  If $Z=pX-qY$ then I think $-qK \le Z \le pK$ and $\mathbb{E}[Z]=0$ and $\text{Var}(Z) = (p+q-2pq)pqK$

Comment: Also asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/454103/119261.

Comment: @Henry Thank you! How do you deduce $\mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(pX-qY)]=\mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(qY-pX)]$ and the value of Var($Z$)?

Comment: @joriki Thank you! I have modified the title.

Comment: @Henry $ReLU(Z) \ge 0 => E[ReLU(Z)] >0 $ ...

Comment: @quester -  I do not disagree with you

Comment: @luw $\mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(pX-qY)]-\mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(qY-pX)] = \mathbb{E}[\text{ReLU}(pX-qY) - \text{ReLU}(qY-pX)]$ $= \mathbb{E}[pX-qY]  = \mathbb{E}[pX]- \mathbb{E}[qY] = pqK-qpK=0$ and $\text{Var}(Z) = p^2\text{Var}(X)+q^2\text{Var}(Y) = p^2q(1-q)K +q^2p(1-p)K$

Comment: @Henry Thank you! I got it!